# Which is the proper usage: a city name or its demonym?

Tags: word-choice, demonyms

Which is the correct usage?

> Oh c'mon New York ... how difficult is it to stay in your traffic lane?

or

> Oh c'mon New Yorkers ... how difficult is it to stay in your traffic lane?

Comment: Why would either be more correct than the other?  They're both subtly different, and both correct.

Comment: People (not cities) drive in lanes, so the second version is more correct than the first. However, I don't think a bit of hyperbole is wasted on a sentiment like that.

Comment: ... Make that synecdoche.

Comment: Does that mean both are correct ? Another example could be.. Are you with me New York ? Or should it be Are you with me New Yorkers?

Comment: It might help you to look up synecdoche. Your use of New York (in both examples) is perfectly acceptable. **All hands on deck** does **not** mean they only want the *hands* slapping the deck.

Comment: Synecdoche, just south of Schenectady.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct usage. There are some minor differences between using "New York" and "New Yorkers" but in your context they basically mean the same thing.